# Running Batch File with PHP on Server 2012 R2 to compile Latex document

Tags: php, batch-file, latex

I am searching for hours at this problem:

I want to compile a Latex document on my webserver running Server 2012 R2 with IIS with PHP.
I created a latex.php:

```
<?PHP
  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
  try {
    echo system('build.bat');
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

In the same directory is the batch file build.bat with the command:

```
"texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex"
```

The batch works perfect if I start it directly on the server in the explorer. If I start ist with PHP it is doing nothing. No log entry at Latex, no log entry in the windows event viewer.
It it just like the command isn't executed.

BUT: If I add the command "md testfolder" this works!!??! So the batch is executed!

- The folder is full rights for everybody and is in my webspace root.
- I am using MikTex 2.9
- Compiling of the .tex file works without errors
- The path to texify is in the system path (also tested with full path in batch)

Anyone some tips how to get more information whats going wrong here?

Comment: put `pause` at the end of the batch to see if it launches and if there is not path issue. Is `testify.exe` in the path? if not put the full path to `testify.exe` i.e `"C:\some path\dir\testify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex"`

Comment: testify.exe is in the path, yes.  pause don't work, because PHP is not opening a commend window!

Comment: In the system path? Or path where the batch file is? Can you try `call` before testify.exe? Or full path to testify?

Comment: Yes it is in the system path. I also tested it with the complete path. Also tried with call. Nothing changed at all...

Comment: ok, can you pipe the output to file so we can see the result? `"texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex" >> output.txt`

Comment: output.txt is empty. I looks like the line is not executed

Comment: if i start the batch in the explorer I get 'texify: warning: running with administrator privileges' and in the output.txt are the complete logs of Latex.But when I use PHP there is nothing.

Comment: Are you running the cmd.exe as admin when you execute manually?

Comment: no, just duobleclick on the batch file. Without settings to run as admin.

Comment: ok, please try this in your batch file `cmd /c "texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex"` if that does not work, try these 2. `start "" "texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex` or `start cmd /c "texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "test.tex"` Sorry I cannot test as I do not have your executables